# How to unpack the key, value of json present in a column of a dataframe is converted into key as columns while value at its values using python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, unpack

I have a data frame:
[image]

I wanted to unpack key, value of each row of json format, present in cast column, into separate columns and their values respectively. So basically, cast_id, character should be separated into columns in the data frame with their respective values.

I have tried:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data_1 = json_normalize(data = casts['cast'], 
                            meta =['cast_id', 'character', 'credit_id', 'gender', 'id','name','order', 'profile_path'])
```

The code is throwing the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

[image]

Comment: Can you please post some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the data set you are using and this will work:

`from ast import literal_eval`
`casts['cast'] = casts['cast'].apply(literal_eval)`

You can now find the cast of each individual movie (for example the first one) by doing
`json_normalize(data=casts['cast'][0])`

If you want a dataframe containing all the cast members of all movies you can do:
`total_cast = pd.DataFrame()`

`for i in range(len(casts)):
    total_cast = total_cast.append(json_normalize(data=casts['cast'][i]))`

Comment: I tried the code you suggested. However, when i am trying to extract dictionaries from the list, it is throwing error of JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2).

Comment: Did you assign the newly created dataframe with the replaced single quotation marks to a new dataframe? The 'assign' function of pandas does not update the dataframe in place. So you have to do casts = casts.assign(cast=lambda x:x['cast'].str.replace("\'", "\"")). En then execute the other function afterwards. Hope this works!

Comment: Yes, I tried that but now the error of JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2416 (char 2415) is coming.

Comment: I looked up the data set you are using. I change the original answer to a solution that should work for clarity.